# How can I best update a part of the DOM that is under v-for loop in Vuejs templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, django-rest-framework, dom-manipulation

In my template

```
<CCard
        class="bg-lams-card-item-1"
        v-for="post in posts"
        :key="post.id"
        style="border-radius: 20px"
      >
        <div
          class="ml-3 pt-1 lams-text-3"
          v-if="post.likes.includes(getUserId)"
        >
          You
          <span v-if="post.total_likes > 1">
            and {{ post.total_likes - 1 }} other<span
              v-if="post.total_likes - 1 > 1"
              >s</span
            >
          </span>
          like this
        </div>....
```

Am also using django Restframework backend with cursor paginator like this

```
class PostsPaginator(CursorPagination):
    page_size = 5
    ordering = 'posted_on'
    cursor_query_param = 'lams'
```

and the view for fetching the posts is as below

```
class PostCreateOrRetrieveAllView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ___Post____\n
    Post get all or create one

    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = PostsPaginator
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(post_by=self.request.user)
```

Everything should be working fine however, after someone hit the like button, i would wish to update the above card's first div and change its innerHtml to my response under ***success*** that I return from my backend as below.

```
{
    "success": "You, and 2 others like this",
    "likes": 3
}
```

But I have even searched on all google but it has not helped, when I try re-rendering the whole posts section, remember it is paginated so you find the currently liked post is paginated out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `v-on:click`?

Exemple :

```js
<buton v-on:click="updateLikes">like this</buton>
```

You can also apply it to span or div ...

```js
<span v-on:click="updateLikes">like this</span>
```

`updateLikes` is the funtion to call when like this is clicked and you will do the treatment behind.

Comment: Thanks for your response but in that div, am not putting any event listener but would like to update it after getting my server response. But the issue is how can I target its internal html.

Comment: Actually I figured another way using arrays. where by I silently mutate the array and it returns the old liked post replaced with the newly fetched object of the same so that I update the whole post all at once.